# PGFPlots bar chart: extra space before the first bar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am creating a bar chart using PGFPlots and it look like this

[image]

I don't want the free space between the y axis and the first bar. I am not sure how to remove this space.

Please help me in figuring out the attribute that controls this space.

Here is the complete version of the code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out if you need a4paper

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
% \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{pgfpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar=1pt,
   ylabel=F1 Score, 
    bar width=10pt,
    x=0.45cm,
    ymin=0,
    axis on top,
    ymax=1,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel style={rotate=-90,  xshift=0.2cm},
   symbolic x coords={barkely hide bones,
cherokee easy tee-shirt,
clorox utility brush, 
cloud b plush bear,
command hooks,
cool shot glue sticks,                
crayola 24 ct,                        
creativity chenille stems ,            
dasani water bottle,                 
dove beauty bar,                      
dr browns bottle brush,              
easter turtle sippy cup ,            
elmers washable no run school glue ,   
expo dry erase board eraser ,         
fiskars scissors red,               
fitness gear 3lb dumbbell,        
folgers classic roast coffee,
hanes tube socks,                      
i am a bunny book,      
jane eyre dvd,                   
kleenex paper towels, 
kleenex tissue box,
kyjen squeakin eggs plush puppies,
laugh out loud joke book,
oral b toothbrush green,
oral b toothbrush red,
peva shower curtain liner,
platinum pets dog bowl,
rawlings baseball,
rolodex jumbo pencil cup,
safety first outlet plugs,
scotch bubble mailer,
scotch duct tape,
soft white lightbulb,
staples index cards,
ticonderoga 12 pencils,
up glucose bottle,
womens knit gloves,
woods extension cord 
},
    visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
    after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
            \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=2pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1.05) -- (rel axis cs:1,1.05);
        },
    nodes near coords={%
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
        },
every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny, inner sep=1pt,rotate=90,xshift=0.3cm},
    axis lines*=left,
    clip=false
    ]
\addplot coordinates {
(barkely hide bones,0.8780)
(cherokee easy tee-shirt,0.8210)
(clorox utility brush,0.8210)
(cloud b plush bear,0.8360)
(command hooks,0.8770) 
(cool shot glue sticks,0.7930)                 
(crayola 24 ct,0.8110)                         
(creativity chenille stems ,0.7610)             
(dasani water bottle,0.7960)                  
(dove beauty bar,0.7400)                       
(dr browns bottle brush,0.9400)               
(easter turtle sippy cup ,0.8790)             
(elmers washable no run school glue ,0.8380)    
(expo dry erase board eraser ,0.8240)          
(fiskars scissors red,0.4780)                
(fitness gear 3lb dumbbell,0.7630)         
(folgers classic roast coffee,0.8980) 
(hanes tube socks,0.8890)                       
(i am a bunny book,0.9060)       
(jane eyre dvd,0.8930)                    
(kleenex paper towels,0.8880)
(kleenex tissue box,0.9420) 
(kyjen squeakin eggs plush puppies,0.8600) 
(laugh out loud joke book,0.8940) 
(oral b toothbrush green,0.7460) 
(oral b toothbrush red,0.6790) 
(peva shower curtain liner,0.9160) 
(platinum pets dog bowl,0.9170) 
(rawlings baseball,0.8580) 
(rolodex jumbo pencil cup,0.9260) 
(safety first outlet plugs,0.8340) 
(scotch bubble mailer,0.8940) 
(scotch duct tape,0.8100) 
(soft white lightbulb,0.8410) 
(staples index cards,0.8470) 
(ticonderoga 12 pencils,0.9500) 
(up glucose bottle,0.7860) 
(womens knit gloves,0.8870) 
(woods extension cord,0.8880)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you show us the code that produces the image? There are several possible causes for this, and taking wild guesses isn't much fun, much better if we can see the code, then we don't have to guess.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem. When I place your code in a minimal document and remove the `...`, I get no space between the first bar and the y-axis (in fact, the bar overlaps the axis). Can you make a complete document, starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}`, that can be compiled without any modifications, and that reproduces the problem? (It should be as little code as possible, but still be a complete document.)

Comment: Added a compilable code and full image of the plot that is generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this can be fixed by adding

```
enlarge x limits=0.03,
```

to the `axis` options, adjust the value according to how much space you'd like to have. `pgfplots` usually adds a little bit of space between the ends of plots and the axes, how and how much is determined by `enlargelimits`/`enlarge x/y limits`, see the manual for a description of the various choices. The setting `x=0.45cm` helps exaggerate the default space that is added.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enlarge x limits=0.03,
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar=1pt,
    ylabel=F1 Score, 
    bar width=10pt,
    x=0.45cm,
    ymin=0,
    axis on top,
    ymax=1,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel style={rotate=-90,  xshift=0.2cm},
   symbolic x coords={barkely hide bones,
cherokee easy tee-shirt,
clorox utility brush, 
cloud b plush bear,
command hooks,
cool shot glue sticks,                
crayola 24 ct,                        
creativity chenille stems ,            
dasani water bottle,                 
dove beauty bar,                      
dr browns bottle brush,              
easter turtle sippy cup ,            
elmers washable no run school glue ,   
expo dry erase board eraser ,         
fiskars scissors red,               
fitness gear 3lb dumbbell,        
folgers classic roast coffee,
hanes tube socks,                      
i am a bunny book,      
jane eyre dvd,                   
kleenex paper towels, 
kleenex tissue box,
kyjen squeakin eggs plush puppies,
laugh out loud joke book,
oral b toothbrush green,
oral b toothbrush red,
peva shower curtain liner,
platinum pets dog bowl,
rawlings baseball,
rolodex jumbo pencil cup,
safety first outlet plugs,
scotch bubble mailer,
scotch duct tape,
soft white lightbulb,
staples index cards,
ticonderoga 12 pencils,
up glucose bottle,
womens knit gloves,
woods extension cord 
},
    visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
    after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
            \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=2pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1.05) -- (rel axis cs:1,1.05);
        },
    nodes near coords={%
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
        },
every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny, inner sep=1pt,rotate=90,xshift=0.3cm},
    axis lines*=left,
    clip=false
    ]
\addplot coordinates {
(barkely hide bones,0.8780)
(cherokee easy tee-shirt,0.8210)
(clorox utility brush,0.8210)
(cloud b plush bear,0.8360)
(command hooks,0.8770) 
(cool shot glue sticks,0.7930)                 
(crayola 24 ct,0.8110)                         
(creativity chenille stems ,0.7610)             
(dasani water bottle,0.7960)                  
(dove beauty bar,0.7400)                       
(dr browns bottle brush,0.9400)               
(easter turtle sippy cup ,0.8790)             
(elmers washable no run school glue ,0.8380)    
(expo dry erase board eraser ,0.8240)          
(fiskars scissors red,0.4780)                
(fitness gear 3lb dumbbell,0.7630)         
(folgers classic roast coffee,0.8980) 
(hanes tube socks,0.8890)                       
(i am a bunny book,0.9060)       
(jane eyre dvd,0.8930)                    
(kleenex paper towels,0.8880)
(kleenex tissue box,0.9420) 
(kyjen squeakin eggs plush puppies,0.8600) 
(laugh out loud joke book,0.8940) 
(oral b toothbrush green,0.7460) 
(oral b toothbrush red,0.6790) 
(peva shower curtain liner,0.9160) 
(platinum pets dog bowl,0.9170) 
(rawlings baseball,0.8580) 
(rolodex jumbo pencil cup,0.9260) 
(safety first outlet plugs,0.8340) 
(scotch bubble mailer,0.8940) 
(scotch duct tape,0.8100) 
(soft white lightbulb,0.8410) 
(staples index cards,0.8470) 
(ticonderoga 12 pencils,0.9500) 
(up glucose bottle,0.7860) 
(womens knit gloves,0.8870) 
(woods extension cord,0.8880)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Welcome to TeX.sx!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)  Always attach your code to your question so that others can find exact cause of your issue and help you quickly.

Else, here is an alternative which may help you. Without using `pgfplots` you can use `bchart` package to draw bar charts. It is very simple to use.

Consider the following code,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{bchart}
\begin{document}

\begin{bchart}[steps={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1},max=1.0]
\bcbar[label=1st bar]{0.88} \bcskip{5pt} % you can set the seperation between bars in the argument of \bcskip
\bcbar[label=2nd bar]{0.82} \bcskip{5pt}
\bcbar[label=3rd bar]{0.82} \bcskip{5pt}
\bcbar[label=4th bar]{0.84} \bcskip{-2.1pt}
\end{bchart}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output,

[image]

To know more about `bchart` package run the command `texdoc bchart` in terminal.